# Cannot find FFT in new LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, fft

I am using Libgdx to analyze sound on Android. I have downloaded libgdx1.6.1 and also 0.9.8 but I cannot use import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.FFT; I have check all .jar libraries in the packages but I cannot find any FFT class. Could any one please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FFT library was removed in April 2014 in preparation for the 1.0.0 release.  See http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3362

You can find the FFT library in the 0.9.2 release:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/0.9.2/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/audio

You may be able to port the code forward, as its mostly independent of the core of Libgdx.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. By the way, do you know when FFT come back in 1.x.x release? I can't find any information about that

Comment: I don't think it will come back unless someone volunteers to maintain it.  You might ask on the badlogic forums for more info and to see if anyone else it using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Pure data, there is a recent libGDX extension here : https://github.com/mgsx-dev/gdx-pd.

Pure data implements FFT and other audio analysis.